# How to execute query (update) stored in table (query)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to execute the result of this query.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] ' + 'SET [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING ([' + COLUMN_NAME + '], 2 , LEN ([' + COLUMN_NAME + ']) - 2) )) WHERE LEFT([' + COLUMN_NAME + '], 1) = ' + '''"''' + ' AND RIGHT([' + COLUMN_NAME + '], 1) = ' + '''"'''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar') 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
```

It return more one row. For example:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ACCDB] SET [ACODI] = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING ([ACODI], 2 , LEN ([ACODI]) - 2) )) WHERE LEFT([ACODI], 1) = '"' AND RIGHT([ACODI], 1) = '"'
UPDATE [dbo].[ANAGP] SET [CDIVA] = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING ([CDIVA], 2 , LEN ([CDIVA]) - 2) )) WHERE LEFT([CDIVA], 1) = '"' AND RIGHT([CDIVA], 1) = '"'
```

Now, how I execute this row programmatically? Without I write every row in stored procedure?

Thanks, I wait answer.

Comment: If you need to simply run these as a one off process, I'd suggest running your query, and the copying the result set into another query window and running them. If, however, you need to do it in one go, You'll need to use a `CURSOR`, and then iterate on that, executing the SQL stored in your variable using `sp_executesql`. I'd also recommend using `QUOTENAME()`, rather than `'[' + TABLE_NAME + ']'` etc. Just *incase* you have any very oddly name objects.

Comment: Just copy paste in SSMS

Comment: IT MUST BE A SCRIPT @Paparazzi

Comment: Search on dynamic sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is dynamic SQL; building your queries on the fly. There are a number of ways to do that. Since you're building multiple statements, you need to be able to execute them one at a time. McNets's answer suggests using a cursor, which is one common way to do what you're after. Another way is to break up your statements with a loop, then execute them one after the other.

The code below gets a list of table names first, defining how many statements we may end up with. Mostly, the ID column is what we care about here. Then there's a WHILE loop to run your query once for each table, with a check to make sure we need to execute the statement for that table.

```
DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(2000) --Variable to hold your query
       ,@Counter INT            --Counter to keep track of where we are in the loop
       ,@EndLoop INT;           --Value to stop the loop

DECLARE @TblList TABLE (
   [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
  ,[Schema] NVARCHAR(128)
  ,[Table] NVARCHAR(128));

INSERT INTO @TblList ([Schema],[Table])
SELECT 
   TABLE_SCHEMA
  ,TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

SELECT @Counter = MIN([ID]), @EndLoop = MAX([ID])
FROM @TblList;

WHILE @Counter <= @EndLoop
  BEGIN

    IF EXISTS ( --If there are no character columns, skip the table
      SELECT 1 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS col JOIN @TblList AS tbl
      ON tbl.[Schema] = col.TABLE_SCHEMA
      AND tbl.[Table] = col.TABLE_NAME
      AND tbl.[ID] = @Counter
      AND col.DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar')
      )
    BEGIN 
      --Construct the query
      SELECT @SqlText = CAST('UPDATE [' + col.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + col.TABLE_NAME + '] ' + 'SET [' + col.COLUMN_NAME + '] = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING ([' + col.COLUMN_NAME + '], 2 , LEN ([' + col.COLUMN_NAME + ']) - 2) )) WHERE LEFT([' + col.COLUMN_NAME + '], 1) = ' + '''"''' + ' AND RIGHT([' + col.COLUMN_NAME + '], 1) = ' + '''"''' AS NVARCHAR(2000))
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS col
      JOIN @TblList AS tbl
        ON tbl.[Schema] = col.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND tbl.[Table] = col.TABLE_NAME
        AND tbl.[ID] = @Counter
        AND col.DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar'); 
      --Run the query
      EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
    END
    --Increment the counter to move through the table list
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;

  END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a CURSOR to execute it line by line.

Have a look at one o my answers on dba.stackexchange.com for a similar question.

[Restore all IDENTITY seeds (out of sync since database restore)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/198839/110455)

Comment: It's the first time that I use T-SQL, so I don't understand what you said..

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @c_Statement VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE StatementCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 'UPDATE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] ' + 'SET [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING ([' + COLUMN_NAME + '], 2 , LEN ([' + COLUMN_NAME + ']) - 2) )) WHERE LEFT([' + COLUMN_NAME + '], 1) = ' + '''"''' + ' AND RIGHT([' + COLUMN_NAME + '], 1) = ' + '''"'''
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar') 
  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME

OPEN StatementCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM StatementCursor INTO @c_Statement

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC(@c_Statement)

    FETCH NEXT FROM StatementCursor INTO @c_Statement

END

CLOSE StatementCursor
DEALLOCATE StatementCursor
```

You may wanna check QUOTENAME() function to wrap object names in quotes instead of hard-coding them in the expression. You also need to check for errors (TRY/CATCH) and validate your user permissions to update the resulting rows.

If you have multiple databases, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS will only list the ones from the current connection.